# Как можно преобразовать List<Class> в List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, классы

При попытке заполнить список "`List<Signal>`" данными типа String из Csv файла возникает ошибка: "Не удается преобразовать String в DataGather.Signal", можно ли как-то преобразовать `List<Class>` в `List<String>`?

```
public static class DataGather
{
    public class Sample : IComparable<Sample>
    {
        public string Time_ms;
        public float VarValue;

        public int CompareTo(Sample other)
        {
            // If other is not a valid object reference, this instance is greater.
            if (other == null) return 1;

            return Time_ms.CompareTo(other.Time_ms);
        }
    }

    public struct Chunk //
    {
        public List<Sample> samples;
    }



    public class Signal
    {
        public string VarName;
        public List<Chunk> chunks;
    }



    // Create a list of signals.
    public static List<Signal> Signals = new List<Signal>();
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете такой странный класс `DataGather`? Какой смысл внутри этого класса создавать кучу вложенных классов и структуру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш код, то примерно так:

```
public static List<Signal> Signals = new List<Signal>();    
List<String> mylist = Signals.Select(Sample=> Sample.Name).ToList();
```